# wxPython app not closing properly

Tags: python, wxpython

For some reason, my program fails to quit properly when my panel is closed when I add the following line:
`dialogRename = wx.TextEntryDialog(None, message = 'Enter the name of the installation:', caption = 'Rename?', defaultValue = addedFilenameUser)`

Even if I never `ShowModal()`, the window closes and I get no errors, but the Python application on Mac OS stays running until I kill it, and "Terminated" is printed on the terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Catch do close event from the main window and do this:

```
wxGetApp().ExitMainLoop()
```

The reason is that your dialog is hidden, not closed. wxWidgets only exit the application when all windows and dialogs are closed.